# XSLT : for-each-group to turn a set of xml nodes into concurrent variables

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-grouping

I'm struggling with the following transformation.

My source is an XML for which I don't know to the root node (it's created on the fly by an ETL and I can't output the XML. Hence the presumed_root).

**XML Source**

```
<presumed_root>
    <IndexGroup>
        <IndexDate>01/01/2017</IndexDate>
        <IndexRate>US_CPI</IndexRate>
        <IndexValue>190</IndexValue>
    </IndexGroup>
    <IndexGroup>
        <IndexDate>01/04/2017</IndexDate>
        <IndexRate>US_CPI</IndexRate>
        <IndexValue>195</IndexValue>
    </IndexGroup>
    <IndexGroup>
        <IndexDate>01/07/2017</IndexDate>
        <IndexRate>US_CPI</IndexRate>
        <IndexValue>193</IndexValue>
    </IndexGroup>
    [...]
</presumed_root>
```

**Desired XML output**

```
<root>
<IndexGroup>
    <IndexRate>US_CPI</IndexRate>
    <IndexNumbers>
        <IndexCode>US_CPI@2017</IndexCode>
        <IndexYear>2017</IndexYear>
        <Month01>190</Month01>
        <Month02/>
        <Month03/>
        <Month04>195</Month04>
        <Month05/>
        <Month06/>
        <Month07>193</Month07>
        [...]
    </IndexNumbers>
</IndexGroup>
</root>
```

So, I'm trying to group values by IndexRate & IndexYear, and put every month in a distinct node.

**Failing XSL**

```
 <xsl:template match="/">

<xsl:for-each-group select="/IndexGroup" group-by="concat(translate(normalize-space(IndexRate),' ','_'),'@',xs:string(year-from-date(xs:date(IndexDate))))"> 
<IndexGroup>

    <xsl:variable name="IndexCode" select="current-group()/translate(normalize-space(IndexRate),' ','_')"/>
    <IndexRate><xsl:value-of select="$IndexCode"/></IndexRate>
    <IndexNumbers>
            <xsl:variable name="IndexCode"><xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()"/></xsl:variable><!-- Code = Index @ Year -->
            <xsl:variable name="Month01"><xsl:value-of select="translate(replace(current-group()[month-from-date(xs:date(current-group()/IndexDate))=1]/IndexValue, '\p{Z}+', ''),',','.')"/></xsl:variable>
            <xsl:variable name="Month02"><xsl:value-of select="translate(replace(current-group()[month-from-date(xs:date(current-group()/IndexDate))=2]/IndexValue, '\p{Z}+', ''),',','.')"/></xsl:variable>
        [...]           
    </IndexNumbers>
[...]
</IndexGroup>
```

With this XML structure & XSL, for-each-group doesn't group anything at all.
Thus, I can't manage to get all months of a year/index combination to be filled at the same time.

Any help would be appreciated, don't hesitate to ask for further explanation / context / input / examples.

Regards,

Comment: Did my answer help or are you still having issues?

Comment: Hi Daniel, thanks for your solution.

Comment: Alas, I'm still having issues : I don't have the same result as you with same source & XSL.

To be more specific, the for-each-group is not grouping.

Which leads me to 2 possible causes :
- Either the source XML doesn't have a root element (possible, since I don't know what's above the IndexGroup nodes)

- Or there's a bug in the embedded XSL interpreter (I don't have access to the product code since I'm only implementing this product).

I'll be just spending a few hours investigating the first case. Otherwise, I'll give up...

Comment: Both those explanations sound unlikely to me, but we can't diagnose your problem unless we know exactly what you are doing and exactly how it is failing, and you aren't giving us enough information. Since I think you're a beginner, it's even possible that you are invoking the transformation incorrectly, so it would help to say how you are running it.

Comment: It has been confirmed by product development team that there's no enclosing top node for each IndexGroup node. Thus my "presumed_root" is indeed void.
With a smart adaptation in the data source itself, I managed to use most of your code with sucess.
Your solution is correct, VERY useful & smart, and thus, accepted !
Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a few issues with your XSLT...

- You are selecting `/IndexGroup` in your for-each-group which would mean the root element of your XML would have to be `IndexGroup`.
- You try to cast `IndexDate` as an `xs:date`, but the format `DD/MM/YYYY` is not a valid xs:date.
- You're creating `xsl:variable`'s instead of literal result elements for the children of `IndexNumbers`
- Since you're grouping by `IndexRate` and then by `IndexRate` + `IndexYear`, I think you need to do two separate for-each-group's.

Here's what I would do...

**XML Input**

```
<presumed_root>
    <IndexGroup>
        <IndexDate>01/01/2017</IndexDate>
        <IndexRate>US_CPI</IndexRate>
        <IndexValue>190</IndexValue>
    </IndexGroup>
    <IndexGroup>
        <IndexDate>01/04/2017</IndexDate>
        <IndexRate>US_CPI</IndexRate>
        <IndexValue>195</IndexValue>
    </IndexGroup>
    <IndexGroup>
        <IndexDate>01/07/2017</IndexDate>
        <IndexRate>US_CPI</IndexRate>
        <IndexValue>193</IndexValue>
    </IndexGroup>
    [...]
</presumed_root>
```

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <root>
      <xsl:for-each-group select="IndexGroup" group-by="IndexRate">
        <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:copy-of select="IndexRate"/>
          <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()" 
            group-by="concat(IndexRate,'@',tokenize(IndexDate,'/')[last()])">
            <IndexNumbers>
              <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
              <IndexCode>
                <xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()"/>
              </IndexCode>
              <IndexYear>
                <xsl:value-of select="tokenize(IndexDate,'/')[last()]"/>
              </IndexYear>
              <xsl:for-each select="1 to 12">
                <xsl:variable name="month" select="format-number(.,'00')"/>
                <xsl:variable name="pattern" select="concat('\d{2}/',$month,'/\d{2}')"/>
                <xsl:element name="month{$month}">
                  <xsl:value-of 
                    select="current-group()[matches(IndexDate,$pattern)]/IndexValue"/>
                </xsl:element>
              </xsl:for-each>
            </IndexNumbers>
          </xsl:for-each-group>          
        </xsl:copy>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
    </root>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<root>
   <IndexGroup>
      <IndexRate>US_CPI</IndexRate>
      <IndexNumbers>
         <IndexCode>US_CPI@2017</IndexCode>
         <IndexYear>2017</IndexYear>
         <month01>190</month01>
         <month02/>
         <month03/>
         <month04>195</month04>
         <month05/>
         <month06/>
         <month07>193</month07>
         <month08/>
         <month09/>
         <month10/>
         <month11/>
         <month12/>
      </IndexNumbers>
   </IndexGroup>
</root>
```